# How to replace nodes in System.Xml.XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

Consider the following xml:

```
<div>
   <a href="http://www.google.com/">This is:</a>
   <p>A test... <b>1</b><i>2</i><u>3</u></p>
   <p>This too</p>
   Finished.
</div>
```

The content of this xml is located in a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` instance. I need to replace all `p` elements and add a break after each paragraph element. I've written the following code:

```
var pElement = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//p");
while (pElement != null)
{
    var textNode = xmlDocument.CreateTextNode("");
    foreach (XmlNode child in pElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        textNode.AppendChild(child);
    }    
    textNode.AppendChild(xmlDocument.CreateElement("br"));
    pElement.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(pElement, textNode);
    pElement = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//p");
}
```

I'm creating an empty node and adding the child nodes of each paragraph node to it. Unfortunately this doesn't work: a text node can't contain elements.

Any ideas how to implement this replace?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)? With LINQ-to-XML this would be two lines of code.

Comment: I'm working on an existing program / framework. That's why the format is an XmlDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution using the `InsertAfter` method:

```
var pElement = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//p");

while (pElement != null)
{    
    //store position where new elements need to be added
    var position = pElement;

    while(pElement.FirstChild != null)
    {
        var child = pElement.FirstChild;
        position.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, position);

        //store the added child as position for next child
        position = child;
    }

    //add break
    position.ParentNode.InsertAfter(xmlDocument.CreateElement("br"), position);

    //remove empty p
    pElement.ParentNode.RemoveChild(pElement);

    //select next p
    pElement = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//p");
}
```

The idea is as follows:

1. Look through all `p` nodes.
2. Loop through all child nodes of `p`.
3. Add them to the correct position.
4. Add a break after each `p` node.
5. Remove `p` element.

The position was quite tricky to find. The first child node needs to be added to the parent node of `p` by using an `InsertAfter` with `p` as the positional element. But the next child needs to be added at the after the previously added child. Solution: save its position and use it.

Note: using a `for each` iterator on the `pElement.ChildNodes` collection won't work, because after moving halve of the nodes, the iterator decides that it is done. Looks like it uses a count of some sort instead of a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `XmlDocument` objects in memory is problematic - see similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967293/remove-parent-node-without-childs-nodes).

The easiest way is to use a XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then you can apply it to your `XmlDocument` using the `XslCompiledTransform` class generating either a string or a stream with the output XML.

Comment: Yeah, I considered XSLT as well, but it looks like killing a fly with a canon, because your basically switching to another domain to solve the problem. It's a solution, but I'm wondering if other solutions would be available.

Comment: Yes, it is another domain, but the correct one to do XML transformations. You can manipulate directly the `XmlDocument`, but the resulting code is very difficult to understand and modify.

Comment: That's true. Although XSLT would be a good solution it might be that working on the XmlDocument is a tad faster is. I've managed to create some code that does the job... it is possible, but not very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're trying to achieve, you could try something like:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(doc.CreateElement("br"), node);
}
```

If I haven't understood right, maybe you could post the output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to replace the `p` nodes. In your case I'm only adding the `br` nodes and I'm not removing the `p`'s.